# Laravel - Add custom styling to the existing app.scss

Tags: php, laravel, sass, css-import

I'm new to Laravel and I've read a few other questions on Stackoverflow about adding custom styling to Laravel.

The reason I'm creating a new stackoverflow question is because Laravel seems to compile a single `app.css`, that also loads bootstrap. I think this is created by running `npm run dev`, which compiles the `app.scss` in the `resources` `sass` folder.

In that given file bootstrap is loaded by `@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';` I'd like to follow this principle too with my own custom styling, so that I get something along the lines of `@import '~mywebsite.css';`

This way I'd end up with a single .css file which I think is far more eloquent.

What's the appropriate way to go about this? Additionally, where is this 'bootstrap' styling located that is being imported? I fail to understand where '~' is located.

Last but not least, is it possible to use the same approach for the `app.js` file?

With much regards,

- Chuck

Comment: ~ is in `node_modules` . Your styles will be in the same folder or possibly subfolders in assets so `@import 'filename.scss'` (for the same folder) or `@import 'subfolder/filename.scss'`) (for subfolders) should be enough.

Comment: So am I right to assume that the 'varables.scss' is not an example of how to place your own css?

Comment: No it's not an example. It's just boilerplate on how you can compile and include bootstrap on your site using bootstrap-sass

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can create a new sass file in /resources/sass for example _test.sass
and put the import in the app.sass like this:

```
@import 'test';
```

and compile with npm run dev or npm run watch

if you need create a new file in your public folder you can create a new sass file (example.sass) and then change the webpack.mix.js file and put your new css line
like this:

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
   .sass('resources/sass/example.scss', 'public/css');
```

and compile with npm run dev.

regards!

Comment: Perfect. I was having doubts about the right approach to some of this basic stuff!

Comment: It is not recommended to import CSS to your SCSS file, and it has been deprecated. Consider converting your CSS file to SCSS first before import